# What is the difference between the selectors #id and [id$='id']?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the difference between two statements:

```
 $("span[id$='id']").text(var);
  // And
 $("#id").text(var);
```

HTML code is : `<span class="normal11" id="id"></span>`

Comment: The first one is the attribute ends with selector and the second one is the id selector. That's all.. :\

Comment: Question title and question body differ... :-?

Comment: [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) vs [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Comment: Don't know why people are down voting this question since the Id-selector uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById() which is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is using *ends with* selector while the second one is using just normal id selector.

[Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

[ID Selector ("#id")](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

By the documentation on JQuery:

`$("#id")` uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. [Link](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

So, the second way should be faster and should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Some different between id selector and attribute selector is

Since id selector called document.getElementById(), 
it only return the first element that have a id equal to that.

However, if you use attribute selector, it will return all elements that have the id attribute that equals to that.

But duplicated id is actually invalid in HTML, and should never used.

if you really want to do that, use class instead.

example

```
$("#id-selector").click(function(){
    $("#test").css("color", "red");
});
$("#attr-selector").click(function(){
    $("*[id=test]").css("color", "blue");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toucyqas/1/